# Stratified samples in R

Tags: r, sampling

I am trying to create **stratified** samples but, getting an error on the columns of my data frame.

FYI: This data frame is created by a sampling process. I am using `splitstackshape` library.

```
library(splitstackshape)
set.seed(1)
out <- stratified(df1, c("x1", "x2"), 30)
head(out)
```

```
> str(df1)
'data.frame':   200 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ y : num  1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 ...
 $ X1: num  -2.111 1.875 0.558 -0.373 0.345 ...
 $ X2: num  -0.36719 -0.00318 -0.3931 1.42763 2.27886 ...
```

Error:

```
Error in `[.data.table`(indt, , `:=`(temp_grp, do.call(paste, .SD)), .SDcols = group) : Some items of .SDcols are not column names: [x1, x2]
```

Comment: This may be an issue with the case of the column name.  You need `c("X1", "X2")`.  However, the sampling issue is alsoo a different one.  The parameter is for group.  These columns are random numbers.  So, it is not clear how you make groups out of it when you specify size as 30.  `If size is a single positive integer, it will be assumed that you want the same number of samples from each group.`

Comment: Yeah, my bad. I fixed it.

Comment: It seems that the problem is that you put the variable names in lowercase while in your data they are in uppercase.

Comment: Perhaps you may need a grouping variable i.e. `df1$group <- 1; stratified(df1, 'group', 30)` if there is a single group, it returns 30 rows

Comment: @akrun Yeah, I want to do stratification on my originally created data to check if the sampling errors are reduced or not. But bit unsure how it is to be written in R, I also read about the `sample_n`

Comment: The error relates to data.table code, but the data-object is not a data.table. What's going on?